# BreezeJs: Update to new metadata from changed BreezeController

Tags: entity-framework, angularjs, metadata, breeze, asp.net-web-api2

I've changed and added some properties to my server-side classes but can't get the updated data in my breeze/angular app. The added fields stay blank instead of showing the value. I also can't create an entity that i've added. (error). How can i update the metadata in my breeze/angular app to use the latest version? I've tried to fetch the metadata, but getting the message that it already was fetched.

```
Breeze: Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: 'New Class'. Be sure to execute a query or call fetchMetadata first
```

***Update (More Info)***

---

I've created a child class related to my Product class. It's called ProductStockItem, so a Product has many ProductStockItems.

***ProductStockItem: (new Class)***

```
public class ProductStockItem
{


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public bool UseStockQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceAdjustment { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateAvailable { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateChanged { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }      

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

***Product:***

```
public class Product
{    
    private ICollection<ProductCategory> _productCategories;
    private ICollection<ProductManufacturer> _productManufacturers;
    private ICollection<ProductPicture> _productPictures;
    private ICollection<ProductSpecificationAttribute> _productSpecificationAttributes;
    private ICollection<ProductStockItem> _productStockItems; 

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public int ParentGroupedProductId { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerSizeId { get; set; }
    public bool VisibleIndividually { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MetaTitle { get; set; }
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public bool LimitedToStores { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string UniqueCode { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal OldPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? SpecialPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SpecialPriceStartDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SpecialPriceEndDateTimeUtc { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountPercentage { get; set; }
    public bool HasTierPrices { get; set; }
    public bool HasStock { get; set; }
    public TaxRate TaxRate { get; set; }
    public bool SyncToShop { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateChanged { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories
    {
        get { return _productCategories ?? (_productCategories = new List<ProductCategory>()); }
        protected set { _productCategories = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductManufacturer> ProductManufacturers
    {
        get { return _productManufacturers ?? (_productManufacturers = new List<ProductManufacturer>()); }
        protected set { _productManufacturers = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductPicture> ProductPictures
    {
        get { return _productPictures ?? (_productPictures = new List<ProductPicture>()); }
        protected set { _productPictures = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductSpecificationAttribute> ProductSpecificationAttributes
    {
        get { return _productSpecificationAttributes ?? (_productSpecificationAttributes = new List<ProductSpecificationAttribute>()); }
        protected set { _productSpecificationAttributes = value; }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductStockItem> ProductStockItems
    {
        get { return _productStockItems ?? (_productStockItems = new List<ProductStockItem>()); }
        protected set { _productStockItems = value; }
    }

 }
```

***Product request:***

```
http://testdomain.local/breeze/DataContext/Products?$filter=Id%20eq%201029&$orderby=Id&$expand=ProductStockItems&

[{"$id":"1","$type":"Erp.Models.ErpModel.Catalog.Product, Erp.Models.ErpModel","Id":1029,"ProductType":"SimpleProduct","ParentGroupedProductId":0,"ManufacturerSizeId":2767,"VisibleIndividually":false,"Name":"Jako Ballenzak Kids - Ash / Action Green","ExtraName":null,"Description":"• Aangenaam functioneel materiaal\nmet moderne oppervlaktestructuur\nvoor de hoogste normen\n• Zeer goede klimaateigenschappen\ndoor actief ademend Twill-Polyester\n• Rekbaar, vormvast en sneldrogend\n\nPolyester-Twill\n100% Polyester,\nbinnenvoering: 100% Polyester","MetaTitle":null,"MetaDescription":null,"DisplayOrder":1,"LimitedToStores":false,"Sku":"9894","UniqueCode":"6_9","Price":34.96,"OldPrice":49.95,"SpecialPrice":null,"SpecialPriceStartDateTime":null,"SpecialPriceEndDateTime":null,"DiscountPercentage":0.00,"HasTierPrices":true,"HasStock":false,"TaxRate":"Tax_21","SyncToShop":true,"Deleted":false,"Locked":false,"State":"Changed","DateChanged":"2014-02-28T10:35:47.733","DateCreated":"2014-02-28T10:35:47.733","ProductCategories":[],"ProductManufacturers":[],"ProductPictures":[],"ProductSpecificationAttributes":[],"ProductStockItems":[]}]
```

***Metadata request:***

```
http://testdomain.local/breeze/DataContext/Metadata
```

***Error Client Side: (create new productStockItem)***

```
Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: 'ProductStockItem'. Be sure to execute a query or call fetchMetadata first.

    function createProductStockItem(initialValues) {
        return this.manager.createEntity("ProductStockItem", initialValues);
    }
```

Comment: Breeze gets the metadata from Entity Framework.  Does Entity Framework know about your new properties and entities?

Comment: Yes it does. I've rebuild everything. When i call the metadata manually I see the new and changed properties.

Comment: Would you provide some more infos like the class you've added new properties to as well as client code.? From the error; 'New Class' is an entity class?

Comment: I've added some more information

Comment: I've changed some values in my database, and removed some properties from a class, but breeze keeps telling me that i must set a value to that "deleted" property? I use the package manager console - update-database -verbose - (Code First) approach.

Answer (score 1):

When you rebuild your application, the metadata will get updated. No extra job needed for making the
metadata to get fetched with it's updated state.

Whenever you issue a query on an entity that is included inside the metadata, the updated metadata
will get fetched.

For creating an entity, if you navigate directly to the page of creating an entity prior to any page that includes a query, the metadata won't get fetched in this case.

When you called `fetchMetadata()`, you still get the error:

```
Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: 'New Class'. Be sure to execute a query or call `fetchMetadata` first
```

That message doesn't indicate that the metadata already was fetched. It still tells you that the entity is unknown and the metadata still not fetched.

Why? Because `createEntity()` was called before `fetchMetadata()`. (you can set a break-point and see that in action)

I ran into this before, and what I did, I simply put the `fetchMetadata()` on application launch.

That will guarantee that it will get fetched first before any call to creating an entity.

Or you can just use a promise:

```
 manager.fetchMetadata().then(createProductStockItem("Initial values"));
```